# Django 'Request' object has no attribute 'user_id'

Tags: python, django, routes, django-rest-framework, query-string

In my `urls.py` I have:

```
url(r'^dashboard/users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/products/$', views.UserProductsList.as_view())
```

in `views.py`

```
class UserProductsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     def get_queryset(self):
         if self.request.user_id:
             return UserProducts.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user_id).order_by('id')
         else:
             return UserProducts.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

I want to be able to access my api as such:

http://localhost:8000/dashboard/users/10/products

should list all products of that user, and

http://localhost:8000/dashboard/users/10/products/1

should return product_id 1 of user_id 10

How can I implement this flow.

> Note: I'm using Django rest framework in this setup

Comment: what about `self.request.user.id` ?

Comment: in my route i've mentioned `(?P<user_id>)` then why would there be anything in `self.request.user.id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
class UserProductsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     def get_queryset(self):
         if self.kwargs['user_id']:
             return UserProducts.objects.filter(user_id=self.kwargs['user_id']).order_by('id')
         else:
             return UserProducts.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

Refer [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url)

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code like this..

```
class UserProductsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
 def get_queryset(self):
     if self.request.user.id:
         return
```

Or

```
class UserProductsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
 def get_queryset(self):
     if self.kwargs['user_id']:
         return
```